# Alamofire download method "Use of undeclared type ´DownloadFileDestination´"

Tags: swift, alamofire

I´m trying to write the method to download a file with custom parameters and headers, but when I write the method XCode shows the Usage of undeclared type 'DownloadFileDestination'

Here's my code:

```
public func download(JSON jsonObject:[String:AnyObject], inUrl url:URLStringConvertible,headers:[String:String]?,paramEnconding:ParameterEncoding) {
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
    Alamofire.download(method: Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, encoding: ParameterEncoding,headers: [String: String]?, destination: DownloadFileDestination) { temporaryURL, response in
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

        return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't put the markdown and still XCode throws the error.

Comment: Where do you have declared `DownloadFileDestination `?

Comment: It's a Alamofire internal class, the line `let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestionation(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)` actually returns a `DownloadFileDestinationInstance`

Comment: @Ces - Yeah, but that final `destination` parameter is expecting the actual closure, not the string "`DownloadFileDestinationInstance`". Frankly, you've got the same problem with all of the parameters: You didn't pass a parameter, but you simply reference the type of value it should be. It looks like you over-zealously hit enter when the code completion showed you what type of parameters the method was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have code that calls `download` like so:

```
Alamofire.download(method: Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, encoding: ParameterEncoding,headers: [String: String]?, destination: DownloadFileDestination) { ... }
```

But all of those parameters, `Method`, `URLStringConvertible`, etc, including `DownloadFileDestination` are the *types* for those parameters. But you should be passing *values* (e.g. instances of objects of those respective types). Most of these parameters were provided as parameters to the method you're defining here, so you'd just use those. I only had to guess what you wanted regarding the http method.

Another curious thing in the code sample is that defined `destination`, calling the `suggestedDownloadDestination` method that builds the closure for you. But you then implemented your own closure. Do one or the other, but not both.

So, eliminating that redundant closure and using the parameters you passed to this method, you get something like:

```
func download(JSON jsonObject: [String: AnyObject], inUrl url: URLStringConvertible, headers: [String: String]?, paramEncoding: ParameterEncoding) {
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
    Alamofire.download(.POST, url, parameters: jsonObject, encoding: paramEncoding, headers: headers, destination: destination)
}
```

I'm guessing you wanted `.POST`. Perhaps you wanted to use `.GET` (but, in that case, it wouldn't make sense to pass `ParameterEncoding` because some encodings only make sense in `POST` request). Or maybe you meant to have a `Method` parameter in your function, itself.

But, setting all of that aside, hopefully you now see why you received the compiler error that you did.

Comment: Thank your for your insights in closures, I just saw the method declaration in the source code and thought that was the way I should use it.